# Proving existence in Isabelle/HOL in this example

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to learn how to use Isabelle/Isar with HOL, and I decided a good way to do that would be to develop some elementary number theory. I defined my own plus and times operations so that proof methods wouldn't be doing all the work for me as there's already plenty proved about +, * in Main. My versions are defined as:

```
fun p:: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" (infix "⊕" 80) where
  p_0: "0 ⊕ n =n" |
  p_rec: " (Suc m) ⊕ n = Suc (m ⊕ n)"

fun t:: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" (infix "⊗" 90) where
  t_0: "0 ⊗ n= 0" |
  t_rec: "Suc m ⊗ n = n + m ⊗ n"
```

and I've already shown that multiplication and addition are commutative the distributive law holds. Then I tried to show the following:

```
lemma euclidean_division_existence: "∃q r. n=q⊗m⊕r"
proof (induction n)
  case 0
  have "0= 0 ⊗ m" by auto
  hence "∃q. 0 =q ⊗ m" by auto
```

but it's telling me it can't finish the proof of the last step. I've tried various things, but I can't figure out how to tell Isabelle I just gave it a witness for the existence statement I'm trying to prove. How can I make Isabelle recognize that?

Edit:

xanonec helped me get past this step, but I immediately got stuck on the next step by a seemingly similar problem. Ultimately I want to show:

```
"∃ q r. 0 = q ⊗ m⊕r"
```

but I can't figure out how to simultaneously introduce the two existentially quantified variable from

```
"0 = 0 ⊗ m ⊕ 0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable strategy for the solution could be a direct rule application (in jEdit you can `cntrl`+LMB or `cmd`+LMB on `exI` to navigate to its statement):

```
lemma euclidean_division_existence: "∃q r. n=q⊗m⊕r"
proof(induction n)
  case 0
  have "0 = 0 ⊗ m" by auto
  hence "∃q. 0 = q ⊗ m" by (rule exI)    
qed
```

More generally, in many similar cases `sledgehammer` can find a suitable (but, often, suboptimal) proof. A tutorial on the use of `sledgehammer` is a part of the official documentation of Isabelle. Also, I would like to suggest the following resources: ["Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL"](http://www.concrete-semantics.org/) by Tobias Nipkow and Gerwin Klein and "A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic" by Tobias Nipkow et al.

---

**An update following an amendment made to the statement of the question**

The following listing presents a proof that relies only on the most basic methods and direct rule application:

```
lemma euclidean_division_existence: "∃q r. n=q⊗m⊕r"
proof (induction n)
  case 0 show ?case
  proof-
    have "0 = 0 ⊗ m ⊕ 0" by simp
    then have "∃r. 0 = 0 ⊗ m ⊕ r" by (rule exI)
    then show "∃q r. 0 = q ⊗ m ⊕ r" by (rule exI) 
  qed
  case (Suc n) show ?case sorry
qed
```

However, if you can afford to rely more on proof automation, then you can use `metis` to prove the entire theorem:

`lemma euclidean_division_existence: "∃q r. n=q⊗m⊕r" by (metis p_0 t_0)`

Comment: That worked for that step, but then I got stuck on the next step. If you can still help, look at the edit I made to the question.